# How to display values based on a selection made in TypeChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Back with another Django question. My application seems to be looking good, but it's time to add some features. Since I'm completely new to Django I can't seem to figure out how to display values in some fields based on a selection the user made. Coming from Delphi it seems to be pretty hard to grasp how those 'lookup values' are handled in Django. So any help would be welcome.

Lets say I have a form which displays a dropdown allowing the user to select a Unit from a dropdown list of available units. Once the user has selected a unit from that list, I would like to display the Type / Name / Description and Image of that unit in some other fields of my form.

Currently I've been able to fill in the list perfectly, but can't seem to figure out how to react on selecting an item from the list :

```
class BaseUnitInputForm(forms.Form):
Name = forms.CharField(
    label="Name",
    max_length=100,
    required=True
)

ParentUnitId = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    label="Parent Unit",
    initial = 0,
    required = True,
)

UnitId = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    label="Indoor Unit",
    choices = [],
    initial = 0,
    required = True,
)

UnitType = forms.CharField(
    label="Indoor Unit Type",
    max_length=100,
    required=True
)

....

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super (BaseUnitInputForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    choice_list = []

    initial = kwargs['initial']       
    parentunitid  = initial['parentunitid']

    # Available units are fetched from a REST server and filtered on the selected
    # Parent Unit ID
    client = RESTClient()
    availableunits = client.get_availableunits(parentunit.parentunitid)

    for availableunit in availableunits:
        choice_list.append((availableunit.Id, "{0} - {1}".format( availableunit.Series, availableunit.Description ) ) )

    self.fields['UnitId'].choices = choice_list
    self.fields['UnitId'].initial = UnitId

    self.helper = FormHelper()

    ...
```

So ... when the user selects a value from the UnitId dropdown, I would like to display the corresponding Series / Description in another ReadOnly field on my form. Any ideas how I could do that ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need client-side code (javascript) for this to work - this is a web application, so once the server returned the HTTP response to the client, things are over (from the server's POV that is).

Comment: Any suggestions on how I could do that?